# can't save point cloud in bag file complitly

Tags: rosbag, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy, i am trying to save the point cloud with size(480,640) in bag file by their coordinate values and then read them in another node so that machine determines which part of the point cloud has been changed in next frames and what are their coordinates so that they can be searched in coming frames and that surface with those points can be detected in next point cloud. My problem is when i save point cloud of size (479,50) range it saves and can be visualized, but as the size change to above 50, i get segmented error, what should i do? My codes are:
To read the point cloud of size(50,50), determined by raw = 479, col = 50:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
#define pi 3.1453
#define pu 3779.527559055
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float32.h"
  #include "std_msgs/Int32.h"
    #include "rosbag/bag.h"
    #include <rosbag/view.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <boost/foreach.hpp>
    #define foreach BOOST_FOREACH

ros::Publisher pub;
ros::Publisher marker_pub;
void
cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> output;
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*input,output);

    pcl::PointXYZ P[479][639];
    for(int raw = 0;raw<479;raw++)
    {
    for(int col = 0;col<639;col++)
    {
        P[raw][col] = output.at(col,raw);
    }
}

int raw = 479, col = 50;

rosbag::Bag bag("test.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Write);
std_msgs::Float32 x[raw][col], y[raw][col], z[raw][col];  // y[480][640], z[480][640];
for(int k=0;k<=raw;k++)
{
    for(int l=0;l<=col;l++)  {
    x[k][l].data = P[k][l].x;
    y[k][l].data = P[k][l].y;
    z[k][l].data = P[k][l].z;
    } }

for(int j=0;j<=raw;j++)  {
    for(int k=0;k<=col;k++)  {
bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), x[j][k]);
bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), y[j][k]);
bag.write("numbers", ros::Time::now(), z[j][k]);
// std::cout<<j<<"\t"<<k<<"\t"<<i[j][k]<<"\t"<<y[j][k]<<"\t"<<z[j][k]<<std::endl;
    }
    }
bag.close();


std::cout<<"saved"<<std::endl;

sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
pcl::toROSMsg(output,cloud);
pub.publish(cloud);
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ROS_INFO("main");
    ros::init(argc, argv,"example");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("input", 1, cloud_cb);
    pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("output",1);
    marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> ("out",1);
    ros::spin();
}
```

And the code for reading them is:(so that if some object moves in depth frame it could be deteted and saved, tracked, since every point in rigid object are always at same position with respect to each other with small error):

```
void
cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> output;
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*input,output);


visualization_msgs::Marker points, line_strip, line_list;
points.header.frame_id = line_strip.header.frame_id = line_list.header.frame_id = "/camera_depth_frame";
points.header.stamp = line_strip.header.stamp = line_list.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
points.ns = line_strip.ns = line_list.ns = "lines";
points.action =line_strip.action = line_list.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
points.pose.orientation.w = line_strip.pose.orientation.w = line_list.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
points.id = 0;
line_strip.id = 1;
line_list.id = 2;
points.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::POINTS;
line_strip.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_STRIP;
line_list.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_LIST;
points.scale.x = 0.01;
points.scale.y = 0.01;
line_strip.scale.x = 0.005;
line_strip.color.b = 1.0;
line_strip.color.a = 1.0;
points.color.r = 1.0f;
points.color.a = 1.0;
line_list.scale.x = 0.005;
line_list.color.a = 1.0;
geometry_msgs::Point p;


pcl::PointXYZ P[479][639];
for(int raw = 0;raw<479;raw++)
{
    for(int col = 0;col<639;col++)
    {
        P[raw][col] = output.at(col,raw);
    }
}
rosbag::Bag bag("test.bag");
//std_msgs::Float32 i[40000], y[40000], z[40000];
float xv[100000], yv[100000], zv[100000]; int iv = -1;

    rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery("numbers"));
     BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
     {
         std_msgs::Float32::ConstPtr i = m.instantiate<std_msgs::Float32>();
         iv = iv+1;
            // std::cout <<"z ="<<"\t"<<iv<<"\t"<< z->data << std::endl;
  

   if(iv%3==0 || iv==0)
         {   if(!isnan(i->data)) {
             xv[iv] = i->data;
             std::cout<<"xv"<<iv<<"\t"<<xv[iv]<<std::endl; }
         }
         else if((iv-1)%3==0 || iv==1)
         {   if(!isnan(i->data))  {
             yv[iv] = i->data;
             std::cout<<"yv"<<iv<<"\t"<<yv[iv]<<std::endl;  }
         }
         else
         {   if(!isnan(i->data))  {
             zv[iv] = i->data;
             std::cout<<"zv"<<iv<<"\t"<<zv[iv]<<std::endl;  }
         }
 }
 bag.close();
 iv = -1;  int raw = 479, col = 50;
 float xp[50][50], yp[50][50], zp[50][50];
 for(int k=0;k<raw;k++)
 {

 for(int l=0;l<col;l++)
 {
     xp[k][l] = xv[++iv];
     yp[k][l] = yv[++iv];
     zp[k][l] = zv[++iv];
     p.x = zp[k][l]; p.y = xp[k][l]; p.z = yp[k][l];
                points.points.push_back(p);
                marker_pub.publish(points);
   } }

    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
    pcl::toROSMsg(output,cloud);
    pub.publish(cloud);
}
```

Here i haven't reduced the code into short, so it looks long, i am just trying to test the concept first then other parts. So what is the problem in saving the hole point cloud with their coordinate values? I'll be really happy if i solved it.

When first node is run it will save cordinates of each point from present point cloud, after saved when we run next node in the same image than it will calculate which points has been changed, if we move an object like screwdriver in image than the points related to it will change along with its coordinates, which the next node will be detecting, than those detected points with their coordinates can be detected, saved as small part of object(since object needs 360 deg of surface), tracked, and after finding 360 deg view oriantation also can be determined. This hole project will work based on principle that every point in a rigid object(human tools) are always at same position with respect to each other. even if object is partially seen, the seen surface can be detected by this method. We dont have to put object over any table to detect them. Color information of point can be also used latter. For this theory to work object has to be rigid, and its not needed to save all the points from given object. Few points, either keypoints or any points form same object can be saved to find it in next frames, by using their relative positions w.r.t each other. right now im saving the points manually by running different node but latter computer will do it itself by using signals and so on. this i added for mr. NEngelhard. :>. it should be noted that even if we save the cordinates  of points, we will be using the positions of points w.r.t other points in same object to detect them, can of course the cordinates of even same point belonging to same object will be different in next view.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241223/can%27t-save-point-cloud-in-bag-file-complitly/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

" segmented error" Please be exact when talking about errors. It's probably an Segmentation Fault.

There are several issues with your code: Using constants like '479' in your code is extremely(!) bad style. A pointcloud has width and height so use these variables. If you want to store a cloud with width of 480, you should also create an array with this size and not one if an entry less (479 instead of 480). (Why do you copy the pointcloud at all in this 2d array?)

But in general: What do you want to do?

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-08-07**:
for computer vision purpose, according to theory this algorithm after completion will able to detect an object in point cloud when moved and than save its 360 deg view by rotating it, and than it is 3d object recognition. we can also add color information latter, than it will also work for 2d image.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-08-08**:
I meant on a lower level. Why do you copy the pointcloud first into an array and the into tons of std_msgs::Float32-Messages to write them into a bag file?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-08-08**:
when first node is run, it will read point cloud and save the cordinates of each points in bag as float, than i will stop this node as it is saved. than in next node it will compare the saved point cloud with present to detect change and so on.  im still trying to figure out how to do it.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-08-08**:
Why don't you store the cloud directly?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-08-08**:
cas i also have to store the point cloud related to moved object, which are fewer in number after this, and also after testing that i have to only save the keypoints of that object(for speed), for pattern recognition, so saving hole point cloud is not solution for me.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-08-09**:
ok i solved this problem, finally.